# Why does the compiler instantiate templates while I ask him not to?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compilation, template-instantiation

I would like to prevent the compiler from implicitly instantiating some template with `extern template`.

The following snippets works as expected (the `static_assert` does not trigger):

```cpp
template<typename T>
void f() {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "f()");
};

extern template void f<int>();

void g() {
    f<int>();
}
```

But with this one it seems that the compiler tries to instantiante the template function, as the `static_assert` does trigger:

```cpp
struct S {
    template<typename T>
    void f() {
        static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "S::f()");
    } 
};

extern template void S::f<int>();

void g() {
    S s;
    s.f<int>();
}
```

with this one, the `static_assert` also triggers whereas I would expect that it does not:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct S {
    S(){};
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "S");
};

extern template struct S<int>;

void g() {
    S<int> s;
}
```

In my actual cases, I would like to speedup compilation times, but I observe that the compilation of translation units  where there is an `extern template ...`, the symbols related to these templates does not appears in the `.o` file (looking with `nm`), but they are actually compiled... (I check that through the observation of significant compilation times with clang's `-ftime-trace` and with `templight++`).

Why does `extern template` does not seems to work as expected?

Thanks!

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0);` is similar to `static_assert(false);` making the template ill-formed NDR.

Comment: Compiler has to do some checks in template, even if not instantiated.

Comment: @jarod I am not sure that `static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0);` is the same as `static_assert(false);` as it depends on the type. The `static_assert` does not trigger for the first snippet, but it would have trigger with `static_assert(false);`

Comment: It is still ill-formed NDR. It is just that making the expression dependent makes harder for compilers to diagnose.

Comment: @jarod I feel that the compiler does more than just some checks in my realistic cases: the time spent (measured with -ftime-trace) for a given template are similar where explicit instantiation occurs than where the compiler implicitly instnatiate the template whereas asked not to

Answer (score 1):

Explicit instantiation declarations can’t suppress *all* instantiation: a class’s **members** must still be known to use an object of that type, after all, and **inline** functions must have their definitions known in order to be inlined.

This example is just both of those in quick succession: the class template can’t “protect” the member function template, and that member function template is inline because it’s defined in its class.

The latter rule is a bit **arbitrary**: it was once considered necessary for ODR reasons, but the modern understanding is that the “merging” of the whole class (template) definition is sufficient.  Accordingly, C++20 removes that implicit `inline` in modules, where it interacts badly with linkage rules.